# Create tables as a view

Tags: mysql, sql

If I create a table like a view of another table or tables
so, if I update or make changes in my another tables.
The table that create from a view will update automatically?

Comment: View are virtual, its just a select statement on another table(s). So there is no need to update it, it will just return the data returned by select statement

Comment: only materialized views do something like that, so no shortcuts

Comment: *The table that create from a view will update automatically?* No. View is dynamic whereas a table created/filled from this view is static and independent.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.